# Windows server 2008 - настройка tcp/ip

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, tcp-ip

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть клиент, посылающий http запросы на сервер. работает через IO completion ports. частота запросов высокая. суть в том, что после перезагрузки машины нагрузка на cpu со стороны приложения составляет порядка 20%, со стороны процесса System - 0-1%, загруженность канала - 60 мбит. после нескольких часов работы нагрузка на cpu со стороны приложения вырастает на 5% и достигает максимума(загружено 1 ядро из 4, программа однопоточная), со стороны процесса System - до 15%, канал падает до 20 мбит. И, что самое ненормальное, после остановки программы и ее последующего запуска нагрузка остается такой же (25% - программа, 15% - System и 20 мбит - канал ). после перезагрузки машины снова 20%, 0-1% и 60 мбит

Собственно вопрос: что можно крутить в настройках tcp/ip что бы понять причину такого поведения?про netsh interface tcp show global знаю, попробовал отключить autotuninglevel - не возымело действия

UPD:Докопался к тому, что основным потребителем процессора является NDIS.SYS. он кушает cpu по нарастающей. это нормально, что по мере работы с сетью он увеличивает свои "аппетиты"?

Comment: Докопался к тому, что основным потребителем процессора является NDIS.SYS. он кушает cpu по нарастающей. это нормально, что по мере работы с сетью он увеличивает свои "аппетиты"?

Answer (score 1):

Решено: в системе был установлен CommView, его драйвера и давали вышеописанный эффект, в частности tsvp.sys. после сноса драйверов проблема исчезла